Using pathlib and shutil.move not moving file into subfolder that does exist
On MacOS I am looping through the source folder of pdf's and checking the destination folder if the there is an existing subfolder with the same name as the file. I am encountering a problem when I run the program it goes directly to my else statement even though the subfolder I know exists. I have tested this on Windows and it works fine but for some reason I can't get it to run successfully on mac. The only thing I can think of is because of the .DS_Store hidden file type that is hanging this up. Here's my existing code
import shutil
import os
from pathlib import Path

source = '/Users/miram/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Company/Docs/Test_SRCDirectory'
dest = '/MAIN/Building-D1D-RFS2'


fileword_target = "CRATE"

#File Rename
for file in Path(source).iterdir():
    name = file.stem.split(fileword_target)[0].rstrip()
    subdir = Path(dest, name)
    print(f"Checking subdir: {subdir}")

#Move file into folder that matches name variable
    if subdir.exists():
        destination = Path(subdir, file.name)
        shutil.move(file, destination)
        print(f"{name} have been moved.")
    else:
        print(f"Folder not found for {name}")

my files I am moving look like this:

filename L1 CRATE D1D

which the .stem/.strip should give me my subfolder name that I am searching for in the destination folder.

"hidden" files like .DS_STORE are only hidden by convention. They are valid as a file path in python. As a guess, if you've got the full path, it may be a problem with a mismatched case one one or more letters in the name. It wouldn't affect case-insensitive Windows machines but could affect mac.

I suggest to reduce files in src and target dir to a minimum (i.e. create a new src and target dir and copy just the files there to reproduce the problem). If you still cannot solve it yourself, add the output of your program and the content of both directories to your post.

The issue is because the os.rename only works if my source and destination are on the same file system (same server) since my locations are mounted differently this does not work. Since moving the source folder to the same server as my destination this now works.
